# Password strength meter in JS works but i want to take into account unique characters

Tags: javascript, function, passwords

I have a function in JavaScript that increments a password strength bar. It only goes of the strings length currently and i want it to increment more if it has unique characters in and a combination of upper and lower case characters.
Below is the current function which does work.

```
var bar = $('#progressbar div');
var password1 = $("#txtNewPassword");
var len = password1.val().length;
bar.css('width', len * 10 + '%');
if (len * 10 < 50) 
{
    bar.css('background', 'red');
} 
else if(len * 10 > 50 && len * 10 < 100) 
{
    bar.css('background', 'orange');
} 
else if (len * 10 >= 100)
{
    bar.css('background', 'green');
    $('#submitPC').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Also I have a submit button that is enabled and disabled when the strength is sufficient enough. I want that to enable the same as it does now but with the new additions. below is the add and remove attribute.

```
if (len * 10 < 100 || password != confirmPassword) 
{
    $('#submitPC').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} 
else 
{
    $('#submitPC').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

I figured i would use a variable set within each conditional statement that would enable the submit dependent on strength rather than just the length like so.

```
if (blnStrength = true && password != confirmPassword) 
{
    $('#submitPC').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} 
else 
{
    $('#submitPC').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Now i want it to include special characters and never to get to 100% unless it contains at least 1 number upper case and lowercase character.
currently `1234567890` or `abcdefghij` would be classed as a **strong** password when it is clearly not. below are a couple of example minimums I would want to be able to use.

`at least 1 number Ucase or Lcase`
**Kieran12345** or something like **K13r4NVen1s0N** Should be secure

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of what you have so far? I have an idea, but it would be much easier to mess with having a live demo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if your password contains desired chars you can use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

To check if it contains a number:

```
hasdigit = /[0-9]/.test(password);
```

Equaly to check for uppercase and lowercase:

```
hasdifferentcase = /[a-z]/.test(password) && /[A-Z]/.test(password);
```

Comment: I am getting syntax errors trying to execute this, under the `=`, is it definitely an assignment i need or a equal to?

Comment: I'ts okay it needed to be wrapped within brackets overall in my if statement :)
This works
`(len * 10 >= 100 && (hasdigit = /[0-9]/.test(password)) && (hasdifferentcase = /[a-z]/.test(password) && /[A-Z]/.test(password)))`

Comment: when you use it this way you dont need the assignment: `if (/[0-9]/.test(passwd) && /[a-z]/.test(passwd)) { ... }`